# Anndroid : How to send broadcast intent to service from notification action?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-service, android-notifications

I'm trying to send a broadcast intent from within a notification action on Android but kind of lost here.

I have an android service that recieves broadcast intents from activities/frgaments and react accordingly, which works fine but I don't know hoe to send one from a notification action.

Service looks something like this.

```
class MyService : Service() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mIntentActionBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(SERVICE_BROADCAST_INTENT))

        val broadcastIntentFilter = IntentFilter()
        broadcastIntentFilter.addAction(SERVICE_BROADCAST_KEY)
        registerReceiver(mIntentActionBroadcastReceiver, broadcastIntentFilter)
    }
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        // onStart
    }

    private val mIntentActionBroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
         override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have notification channel where the user performs certain actions, it looks something like this.

```
val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, PRIMARY_CHANNEL)
    .addAction(getCustomAction(context))

    private fun getCustomAction(context: Context): NotificationCompat.Action {
        val actionIntent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java).apply {
            action = NOTIFICATION_ACTION_CUSTOM
        }
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, actionIntent, 0)
        return NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_custom_48dp, "", pendingIntent)
    }
```

When the user click the action in the notification, it seems to re-call MyService onStartCommand again, thus certain state of my service is messed up.

Instead, is it possible to send a broadcast intent from `getCustomAction()` and recieve it in the service and do something with it?

Would something like this be possible within `getCustomAction()`?

```
val intent = Intent(SERVICE_BROADCAST_INTENT)
intent.putExtra(SERVICE_BROADCAST_KEY,  NOTIFICATION_ACTION_CUSTOM)
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to send a broadcast intent from getCustomAction() and recieve it in the service and do something with it?

You could have the service register a system broadcast receiver (`registerReceiver()` on `Context`), then send a system broadcast to it (`sendBroadcast()` on `Context`) using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` to create the `PendingIntent`.

Or, fix the service to address "thus certain state of my service is messed up".

> Would something like this be possible within getCustomAction()?

No, because the sender is another process, not yours. `LocalBroadcastManager` only works within your own process.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, could you please share example on how to registerReciever as a context of service?